# Replace expressions

Tags: replacement, rule

Let's consider the following example

```
Rd0 = Sqrt[R^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2];
Rn0 = Sqrt[R^2 + z^2] - rs;

Vd = -Md/Rd0;
Vn = -Mn/Rn0;

Veff = Vd + Vn + Lz^2/(2*R^2);

VR = D[Veff, R];
```

The expression `VR` gives

```
-(Lz^2/R^3)+(Mn R)/(Sqrt[R^2+z^2] (-rs+Sqrt[R^2+z^2])^2)+(Md R)/
 (R^2+(a+Sqrt[h^2+z^2])^2)^(3/2)
```

Now I want to replace some expressions, using the rule

```
rule = {Sqrt[h^2 + z^2] -> Rdz; Sqrt[R^2 + z^2] -> Rcn; 
          (R^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2)^(3/2) -> Rd^3};
```

However, when I apply it as `VR /. rule1` I get

```
-(Lz^2/R^3)+(Mn R)/((Rcn-rs)^2 Sqrt[R^2+z^2])+(Md R)/
 (R^2+(a+Sqrt[h^2+z^2])^2)^(3/2)
```

As we see, only one of the terms has been replaced, while all the others have not been replaced. So my question is: how can I efficiently replay all the expressions according to the above rule?

Comment: It seems to me that the semicolon in 'rule' in the first entry is a typo: the second expression you seem to want is lost. Changing it to a comma already makes your expression simpler

Comment: @JJBK I corrected the typo but the problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

As often with replacements in mathematical expressions, the problem is that the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of an expression is not what we might think it is. In this case, consider the second term of `VR`:

```
VR[[2]]//FullForm
(* Times[
    Mn,
    R,
    Power[Plus[Power[R,2],Power[z,2]],Rational[-1,2]],
    Power[Plus[Times[-1,rs],Power[Plus[Power[R,2],Power[z,2]],Rational[1,2]]],-2]
   ] *)
```

Notice the `Power[…,Rational[-1,2]]` expression for the $1/\sqrt{\cdots}$ part. This means you need to adapt the pattern to handle both `1/2` and `-1/2` as exponent. The easiest way to do this here is:

```
rule = {
   Sqrt[h^2 + z^2] -> Rdz,
   (R^2 + z^2)^Rational[s : -1 | 1, 2] :> Rcn^s,
   (R^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2)^Rational[s : -3 | 3, 2] :> Rd^s
   };
```

Note the use of `Rational[…, 2]` as opposed to `…/2` - the problem is that we have to explicitly write out the `Rational` head, since `…/2` does not get converted to a `Rational` if `…` is not an explicit integer:

```
Head /@ {
  1/2,
  -1/2,
  (s : -1 | 1)/2,
  Rational[s : -1 | 1, 2]
  }
(* {Rational, Rational, Times, Rational} *)
```

Now, the replacements work as expected:

```
VR /. rule
(* -(Lz^2/R^3) + (Md R)/Rd^3 + (Mn R)/(Rcn (Rcn - rs)^2) *)
```